# Save the specified path to a alredy existing .bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

It is possible to point out a directory with this script and save the pointed out path to a existing .bat file? This script opens a folder select prompt.

**The bat file**

```
ECHO off
set PATH=C:\folder
forfiles.exe /p %PATH% /s /d -730 /c "cmd /c del /q /f @file"
```

---

The vbscript code :

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Echo BrowseFolder( "C:\Program Files", True )
WScript.Echo BrowseFolder( "My Computer", False )
WScript.Echo BrowseFolder( "", False )


Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog )
' This function generates a Browse Folder dialog
' and returns the selected folder as a string.
'
' Arguments:
' blnSimpleDialog   [boolean] if False, an additional text field will be
'                             displayed where the folder can be selected
'                             by typing the fully qualified path
'
' Returns:          [string]  the fully qualified path to the selected folder
'
' Based on the Hey Scripting Guys article
' "How Can I Show Users a Dialog Box That Only Lets Them Select Folders?"
' http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/jun05/hey0617.mspx
'
' Function written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com
    Const MY_COMPUTER   = &H11&
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

    Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
    Dim objPath, objShell, strPath, strPrompt

    ' Set the options for the dialog window
    strPrompt = "Select a folder:"
    If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
    numOptions = 0      ' Simple dialog
    Else
        numOptions = &H10&  ' Additional text field to type folder path
    End If

    ' Create a Windows Shell object
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    ' If specified, convert "My Computer" to a valid
    ' path for the Windows Shell's BrowseFolder method
    If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        strPath = objFolderItem.Path
    Else
        strPath = myStartLocation
    End If

    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
                                          numOptions, strPath )

    ' Quit if no folder was selected
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        BrowseFolder = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Retrieve the path of the selected folder
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path

    ' Return the path of the selected folder
    BrowseFolder = objPath
End Function
```

Comment: Important note regarding your submitted batch file example. As soon as you replaced the content of the important existing variable `%PATH%` with `C:\folder`, unless your current directroy was `C:\Windows\System32`, or you had a file named `forfiles.exe` in `C:\folder`, the command line beginning `forfiles.exe` will very likely fail. Do not modify the content of `%PATH%`, unless you really know what you're doing and the repercussions of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your request, you want select the path of the source folder and set it as variable.

Here is an example that use a powershell in a batch file for selecting folders :

---

```
@echo off
Title Folder Selection
echo(  Please choose your source folder . . .
call:FolderSelection "%SourcePath%", SourcePath, "Please choose your source folder"
echo(  You have chosen the following source folder  : "%SourcePath%"
pause
EXIT
Rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:FolderSelection <SelectedPath> <folder> <Description>
SetLocal & set "folder=%~1"
set "dialog=powershell -sta "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms^
|Out-Null;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;$f.SelectedPath='%~1';$f.Description='%~3';^
$f.ShowNewFolderButton=$true;$f.ShowDialog();$f.SelectedPath""
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%dialog%') do set "res=%%I"
EndLocal & (if "%res%" EQU "" (set "%2=%folder%") else (set "%2=%res%"))
exit/B 0
Rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @qwerty95 Please avoid choosing your Variable as `%Path%` change it as `%SourcePath%` after you call your function `call:FolderSelection "%SourcePath%", SourcePath, "Please choose your source folder"` the variable is stored as `%SourcePath%` and you can continue into your batch file with this : `forfiles.exe /p %SourcePath% /s /d -730 /c "cmd /c del /q /f @file"`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably delete all files older that 730 days, within a directory tree selected via a GUI dialog, with a single line command from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) using the assistance of [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Nologo -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'Select your directory.',1,0).Self.Path -File -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-730) } | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf"
```

Please note that the command currently only shows you what it would delete, *(you'd obviously need to add a `pause`, or something, if you're running your batch file from the GUI, and wanted to see that before the window closes)*. If you're satisfied with the results, just remove  `-WhatIf` towards the end of the line.